# CGContextRef not being created

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, quartz-2d

```
-(CGImageRef)drawing{

CGContextRef    context;
GLubyte         *bitmapData;
size_t          width, height;

width=super.size.width;
height=super.size.height;

bitmapData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width * height * 4, sizeof(GLubyte));

context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData, width, height, 8, width * 4, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

if (context==NULL){
    NSLog(@"context not created?!   (o_*) ");
}

free(bitmapData);


CGContextSetRGBFillColor (context, 1, 0, 0, 1);
CGContextFillRect (context, CGRectMake (0, 0, 200, 100 ));
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (context, 0, 0, 1, .5);
CGContextFillRect (context, CGRectMake (0, 0, 100, 200 ));




CGImageRef myImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (context);

CGContextRelease(context);

return myImage;

}
```

So i'm trying to render a drawing off screen in a context and then get it as a `CGImageRef` but for some reason the context is always NULL and the app crashes when i read the image output.

Can someone explain what's going on here and / or point me to an example where this works.

Comment: Is there anything in the console? There may be a message about what is wrong trying to create the context.

Comment: @rmaddy only <Error> CGContextSetRGBFillColor: invalid context 0x0   but that should be there because the context is null. Other than that nothing...and that's what's puzzling me

Comment: Try replacing your color space with `CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB)`. BTW - you need to release the color space.

Comment: How big are `width` and `height`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the context is null - the width & height might be bad.

But...

1. You're freeing the bitmap before you use it!
2. You can't release the color space you create.

There's an example using `CGBitmapContextCreate` in the Quartz 2D Programming Guide.

Comment: It was actually the width and height..but for a stupid reason. The width and height wore CGFloats and when i passed those to CGBitmapContextCreate it crashed..but when i type casted into int it worked. If you pass float to an int shouldn't it be read as an int? Or my years of college wore for nothing?